# Grab last 5 items of a Collection/List/Dictionary in C#?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a class:

```
public class MatchItem
{
    public string round { get; set; }
    public string player1 { get; set; }
    public string player2 { get; set; }
    public string scores { get; set; }
}
```

Originally I was using a Dictionary:

```
private Dictionary<string, MatchItem> results = new Dictionary<string, MatchItem>();
```

A dictionary allows me to access the MatchItem values using a hashed string as the index key.

However, now I have a new need. I would like to be able to access the last X number of items added to the dictionary. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: You can't reliabilly do that with a dictionary, you will need to keep a 2nd collection that maintains order

Comment: When you say "last" you should be ordering items by a paremeter. What is the sort parameter? How can we decide which items are the last ones?

Comment: A dictionary is not the correct data structure for this purpose. There's no notion of order in it. It's just a hashtable.

Comment: What would be the correct data structure then?

Comment: Maybe a `List<MatchItem>` or `MatchItem[]`.

Comment: Probably List<T> if you provide a sorting parameter.

Comment: I dont understand what you guys mean by sorting parameter...

Comment: You can use `OrderedDictionary` type - that gives you fast lookups, and a consistent sequence. Sadly, it doesn't have a generic version, but it should perform well for your purposes.

Comment: if update time is generally a property of `MatchItem` you can also consider making it a property - still would need a O(n) lookup time iterating through the collection and getting the top 5 (or ordering them by update time then taking 5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the last `X` items using `Skip` method but you should keep in mind that `Dictionary` does not have an order, so this might not work as expected, but it will work for ordered collections such as `List<T>`:

```
var items = results.Skip(results.Count - 5).Select(x => x.Value);
```

Comment: Or you could `Reverse` and then `Take(5)`

Answer (score 0):

If you definitely have to keep your values in a dictionary then you will need a helper collection that keeps order of entries or time of entry. In my example I packed it in a very simple wrapper class `OrderedDictionary` but it doesn't mean you have to have a wrapper class. Easily you can add the helper collection that keeps time of entry to the class where you have your dictionary.

When adding an entry to the dictionary you will have to update the helper dictionary. Here I went for DateTime.Now.Ticks to keep order of entries. Then, when returning items I sort the collection in descending entry time, get requested amount of keys, search these keys in the main dictionary and return the result.

```
public class OrderedDictionary<T, K>
{
    private Dictionary<T, K> baseDictionary;
    private Dictionary<long, T> entryTimeDictionary;

    public OrderedDictionary()
    {
        this.baseDictionary = new Dictionary<T, K>();
    }

    public void Add(T key, K val)
    {
        this.baseDictionary[key] = val;
        this.entryTimeDictionary[DateTime.Now.Ticks] = key;
    }

    public List<KeyValuePair<T, K>> GetLastEnteredItems(int numberOfEntries)
    {
        // Find n last keys.
        var lastEntries = 
            this.entryTimeDictionary
                .OrderByDescending(i => i.Key)
                .Take(numberOfEntries)
                .Select(i => i.Value);

        // Return KeyValuePair for itmes with last n keys
        return this.baseDictionary
                   .Where(i => lastEntries.Contains(i.Key))
                   .ToList();
    }
}
```

As said before, you can use the same mechanism in your class. If you however decide to create your own wrapper class it should probably implement IDictionary, ICollection, and IEnumerable interfaces.